Execute 'logout' method when closing chrome
I'm working on a chat support system and I need to keep the current status and the time that the user has been logged to that status even when the user navigate through different pages or refresh the page. The script that controls the status and update the database is on the _layout.cshtml page that all the pages in the system inherit. When the user click on the menu 'logout' the system clears all the localstorage data, the session and updates the users status on the database by executing the method 'logout'
Everything described above is working, but, I cannot trigger the 'logout' method when the user closes the browser or the tab and make the system keep the data when the user navigate in between pages or refresh the page. I'm using vue.js and asp.net core.
   new Vue({
       el: '#layout-wrapper',
       data: {
           currentStatus: localStorage.getItem('currentStatus') || 'Offline',
           elapsedTime: localStorage.getItem('elapsedTime') || '00:00:00',
           startTime: localStorage.getItem('startTime') ? new                    Date(localStorage.getItem('startTime')) : new Date(),
           intervalId: null
       },
       mounted() {
           this.startTimer();
           this.attachBeforeUnload();
       },
       methods: {
           startTimer() {
               // Use setInterval to keep calculating elapsed time
               this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                   this.elapsedTime = this.calculateElapsedTime();
                   localStorage.setItem('elapsedTime', this.elapsedTime); // Persist in localStorage
               }, 1000);
           },
           calculateElapsedTime() {
               const now = new Date();
               const elapsed = new Date(now - this.startTime);
               return elapsed.toISOString().substr(11, 8);  // Format as HH:mm:ss
           },
           updateStatus(newStatus) {
               axios.post('/api/agent/updateStatus', { status: newStatus })
                   .then(response => {
                       this.currentStatus = newStatus;
                       localStorage.setItem('currentStatus', newStatus);
                       this.resetTimer();  // Reset the timer when status is updated
                   })
                   .catch(error => {
                       console.error('Erro ao atualizar status:', error);
                   });
           },
           resetTimer() {
               clearInterval(this.intervalId);
               this.startTime = new Date();
               localStorage.setItem('startTime', this.startTime.toISOString());  // Persist start time in localStorage
               this.elapsedTime = '00:00:00';
               localStorage.setItem('elapsedTime', this.elapsedTime);
               this.startTimer();  // Restart the timer
           },
           logout() {
               axios.post('/api/agent/logout')
                   .then(response => {
                       // Clear stored values on logout
                       localStorage.removeItem('elapsedTime');
                       localStorage.removeItem('currentStatus');
                       localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
                       window.location.href = '/Painel/Login';
                   })
                   .catch(error => {
                       console.error('Erro ao sair:', error);
                   });
           },
           attachBeforeUnload() {
               window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
                   if (!this.isInternalNavigation()) {
                       this.logout();
                   }
               });
           },
           isInternalNavigation() {
               return window.location.pathname.startsWith('/Painel');  // Check if navigation is within the system
           }
       },
       beforeDestroy() {
           window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.attachBeforeUnload);
       }
   });

I tried creating the verification above but it did not work

This is XY problem. If you want to make a request on browser close, use beacon api. There's no other way to do this reliably. This is not related to local storage. You'll have to clean it the next time a user won't be authenticated. Use session storage instead of LS if you don't want it to persist

If you'd like to clear your local storage when the user closes the browser, I'd use sessionStorage instead of localStorage as it'll automatically clear once the user closes the browser. You won't have to worry about clearing those items.

"I cannot trigger the 'logout' method when the user closes the browser or the tab and make the system keep the data when the user navigate in between pages or refresh the page." => For the page navigation, if you mean use the hyperlink to navigation, we can prevent the logout using the beforeunload event, but if you are using the browser's back/forward or refresh button the refresh the page, we can't prevent it via the beforeunload event, because we can't capture the browser's back/forward via JS, and it will also trigger the beforeunload event.
